# SQL-Server migration assistant (SSMA) Sybase License

Tags: sql-server

It appears that Microsoft's "license registration download" for Sybase is returning a 404 error now.  SSMA was downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28765 .

I found a blog post that points to the Accsss license download (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=18589), but nothing for Sybase yet.  I'm hoping one of you have either worked thorough the Microsoft support gauntlet, or were able to snag a license before the page went offline.  Apparently it has been broken for a few months now.

Thanks in advance

John

Comment: I just opened a support case with Microsoft for this very problem. When I get the correct link I will post it. The product I'm using (trying to use) is SQL Server Migration Assistant V5.2 for Sybase ASE. I installed it last November on another server and the link worked fine then.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft sent me a license file but unfortunately it is only for my company and I can't share it.  The link hasn't changed but they said that the license website was being worked on and hopefully will be back up in a couple of days.

Comment: I've seen blog posts saying it has been down since October, so I'm not holding my breath.  How did you request the license from Microsoft?  Is there an email that they actually respond to, or a particular web-form you filled out?